# A complaint of over-moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'd like to complain about [my question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/275837/117932) and its [self answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/275843/117932).

Another member has probably mistaken my answer as an expansion of the question, probably because it began with "a bit of context". But the content of that answer is a concrete example of security risk that I've asked for in the question. Then later, a moderator moved the content of that answer to the question body, and deleted the answer.

Since it's deleted by a moderator, I cannot vote to undelete it. But honestly, the whole point is: that's not an expansion of the question, that's my self-answer, albeit not complete yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, it wasn't quite an answer yet. As prep for an answer, it acts as an expansion of the question and not an answer.

Comment: I've edited it since. Can it be restored in your opinion? Or what do you see still missing?

Comment: I undeleted your answer